# So I try building my flutter code and get the error

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the error i get

> /H:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:277:51: Error: Too many positional
> Try removing the extra positional arguments.
> context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)

And this is the code snippet in question

````
    final chewieControllerProvider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
            as _ChewieControllerProvider;```
````

Comment: `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` doesn't have any positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final chewieControllerProvider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ChewieControllerProvider>();
```